# Using SQL in SAS, how do I create a new column that counts/indicates the uniqueness of values in an existing column..?

Tags: sql, sas, counting

My data is as follows:

```
ID
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
6
```

I want to create a column that indicates the uniqueness of a value in the ID column as such:

```
ID  COUNT
1   1
2   1
3   1
3   0
4   1
5   1
6   1
6   0
```

I'd like to do this without creating a temporary table, via a subquery or something. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you forced to use `proc sql` (as in a homework question)?

Comment: I'm really not even sure where to start to be honest, but my preference for SQL is because we will be moving from SAS to Oracle in the near future.

Comment: You can use plain SQL to get that flag: `select id, case when row_number() over (partition by id order by id) = 1 then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: You should be aware that SAS SQL is very different from Oracle SQL. You're not going to be able to just copy and paste between them.

Comment: @dnoeth that would not be valid SAS SQL, there's no row_number() or partition concepts.

Comment: I don't understand how your desired output measures the uniqueness.  You seem instead to be creating a flag that is true only once per group.  Remember that SQL has no provision for ordering of individual records.  If you need that in pure SQL you will need to use an advanced SQL implementation that supports windowing functions.

Comment: @JoshEller thanks for the intel but yes, I am aware - just trying to reduce the amount of conversion, even if it won't be totally seamless.

Comment: @Tom I agree, that's a much better way to phrase it. But it sounds like I've stumbled onto something that's not really feasible...in which case can anyone tell me how best to proceed with closing this post? Or what's my best move here? (Sorry I'm brand new).

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use by functionality in the data step:

```
data have;
input ID;
datalines;
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
6
;run;

data want;
set have;
by ID;
if first.ID then count = 1;
else count = 0;
run;
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, but I'm trying to move away from data steps given we will be moving away from SAS in the near future.

Comment: This isn't easy in SQL do you have another variable that would indicate the 'first' record, such as a date or something?

Comment: @Reeza unfortunately I do not...sounds like I might be out of luck here?

Comment: Honestly, not worth the effort in my opinion. Mark it as part that needs to be updated when you transition to Oracle. However, even with a partition, you cannot guarantee which record will be marked which you could keep consistent in a data step so you're not going to get the same results from your processes. I guess if it doesn't matter you're likely fine.

Answer (score 0):

That type of logic is not really amenable to SQL since the order of observations is not really insured.  In a more modern version of SQL you could use windowing functions (like ROW_NUMBER() with PARTITION BY) to impose an record count.

If you really wanted to try to do it just in PROC SQL you might need to resort to using the undocumented `MONOTONIC()` function.  But even then to defeat the optimizer eliminating the duplicate rows you might need to make a temporary table with the row counter first.

```
data have;
  input ID @@;
datalines;
1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6
;

proc sql ;
  create table _temp_ as select id,monotonic() as row from have;
  create table want as
    select a.id
         , b.row=min(b.row) as FLAG
    from have a,_temp_ b
    where a.id=b.id
    group by a.id
    order by 1,2
  ;
quit;
```